# How can I get python-crontab to work in PyCharm?

Tags: python

Installed python-crontab in Pycharm but falling at the first hurdle

I'm using Pycharm and installed python-crontab via settings - Project interpretor. I then tried to follow the instructions but with no luck.  I tried this with and wthout the import CronTab part..

```
from crontab import CronTab
cron = CronTab(tabfile='Code1.py')
```

I get the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/lisa/PycharmProjects/Driving/crontab.py", line 2, in <module>
    cron = CronTab(tabfile='Code1.py')

NameError: name 'CronTab' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Can you try renaming your python file from `crontab.py` to something else? Bad idea to name a file with the same name as a module you are importing

Comment: That did seem to work!  Thank you very much and I will keep this in mind in future